# I need help creating a background loop in python

Tags: python, multithreading

So I'm coding a small project with my cousin, but since we're not experienced with Python 3.x, we cannot create a background while loop for one of my items that you can buy in the shop. I am the only one who has the slightest of experience in multithreading (which, mind you, I barely know anything about), so I've searched everywhere for a solution, to which I didn't. Here is my code so far:

```
import time
import random
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import threading
from queue import Queue

print_lock = threading.Lock()




def cap_scavengerJob(worker) :
    player_value = 0
    scav = 0
    magnet = 0
    press = 0

    print()
    print("Welcome to Cap Scavenger!")
    print()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Searching for caps.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Searching for caps..")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Searching for caps...")
    time.sleep(1)

    start_chance = random.randint(65,125)
    print("You have found ", start_chance ,"caps!")
    player_value = player_value+start_chance
    print("Your goal is to find as many caps as you can!")

    while True :
        decision_search_1 = input("Would you like to (search) for more caps, (check) how many caps you have or go to the (shop)? \n")
        if decision_search_1 == "search" :
            print("Searching for caps.")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Searching for caps..")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Searching for caps...")
            time.sleep(1)
            search_chance = random.randint(0,100)
            if search_chance >= 50 :
                cap_chance = random.randint(10,50)
                print("You have found ", cap_chance ,"caps!")
                player_value = player_value+cap_chance
                print()
                print("You now have", player_value ,"caps!")
                print()

            elif search_chance >= 85  :
                cap_chance = random.randint(5,10)
                print("You have found", cap_chance ,"caps!")
                player_value = player_value+cap_chance
                print()
                print("You now have", player_value ,"caps!")
                print()

            elif search_chance >= 40 :
                cap_chance = random.randint(25,75)
                print("You have found", cap_chance ,"caps! You got lucky!")
                player_value = player_value+cap_chance
                print()
                print("You now have", player_value ,"caps!")
                print()

            elif search_chance >= 25 :
                cap_chance = random.randint(40,120)
                print("You have found", cap_chance ,"caps! You got lucky!")
                player_value = player_value+cap_chance
                print()
                print("You now have", player_value ,"caps!")
                print()

            elif search_chance <= 10 :
                cap_chance = random.randint(60,250)
                print("You have found", cap_chance ,"caps! You hit the jackpot!")
                player_value = player_value+cap_chance
                print()
                print("You now have", player_value ,"caps!")
                print()

            else :
                print("You haven't found any caps.")
                print("You now have", player_value ,"caps!")

        elif decision_search_1 == "shop" :
            print("Welcome to the shop!")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Here you can buy items which will produce caps, making your job easier!")
            time.sleep(1)
            shop_option = input("Would you like to (buy) or (exit)? \n")
            time.sleep(0.4)
            while shop_option == "buy" :
                print("(S)cavenger (10 caps per second) : 500 caps")
                print("(C)ap magnet (20 caps per second) : 1000 caps")
                print("(F)actory cap press (100 caps per second) : 5000 caps")

                buy_option = input()

                if buy_option == "S" :
                    if player_value < 500 :
                        print("Sorry, you don't have enough caps. Get more!")
                    elif player_value >=500 :
                        player_value = player_value-500
                        scav = scav+1
                        print("Thank you for purchasing a Scavenger, you now have ", scav ,"Scavengers!")

                        shop_option = input("Please enter anything to exit the shop. \n")

        elif decision_search_1 == "check" :
            print("You have ", player_value ,"caps!")
            print("You have ", scav ,"Scavengers!")
            print("You have ", magnet ,"Cap magnets!")
            print("You have ", press ,"Factory cap presses!")

        elif decision_search_1 == "debug_mode" :
            print("Debug Mode activated!")
            player_value = player_value+10000


def scav_loopJob(worker):
    while True:
        player_value += 1
        time.sleep(1)

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        cap_scavengerJob(worker)
        q.task_done()

def threader():
    while True:
        worker = q.get()
        scav_loopJob(worker)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()

for x in range(1):
    t = threading.Thread(target = threader)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

start =time.time()

for worker in range(20):
    q.put(worker)

q.join()
```

What I really need help with is how to run the main program and the scav_loop simultaneously, and I also need to know some aspects of multithreading XD. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You probably have to narrow your question and define what exact problem you have. How is your cousin by the way?

Comment: what is the *scav_loop*?

Comment: Now honestly this problem is probably a lot easier than you are making it to be, so try making a new window and doing the "Shop" code and playing around with it. In other words strip it down to the bones to find what is wrong with it.

Comment: The thing is that when you buy a certain item in the shop (the scavenger for this case) it is supposed to add 1 to your player value every second, but since I'm so crap at multithreading, it doesn't.

Comment: the scav loop is the while loop for adding the player value

Comment: I'm new to this so thanks :D i'll try it

Comment: This is going to need a lot more locking than you are actually doing.  `player_value = player_value+10000`, for example, will not play well with `player_value += 1` unless they are mutually excluded (since each is actually three separate operations: 1. Get the current value of `player_value`, 2. Calculate the new value, 3. Store the new value).

Comment: ok, i'll try, but I barely have any experience with this multithreading kind of stuff.

Comment: [Threads are hard](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/121).  There is only so much advice we can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you need is a background loop if you're new to Python you better use math to simulate the time, instead, but, that's my very personal point of view. I permitted myself to review / rewrite your code as I found some errors like not following the PEP8 rules, or obvisouly wrong `if/elif/elif/elif` blocks, etc...

My proposition here is far from perfect, but should start to help you organise yourself in a better way. Keey your code readable, keep your variables correctly named, keep your methods correctly named, just be able to read yourself tomorrow.

Hope that helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import random
from datetime import datetime


"""
1) Trying to use 'input' from like 20 thread simultaneously is probably
   not a great idea.
2) You should read the PEP8
3) Good thing you're using Python 3 :-)
4) You should write shorter methods, aroudn 25 lines max
5) Why do you need background tasks ?

If you think you need background tasks to increment a variable each
second, that's probably not the easier way to start. A good may may
probably better to "simulated" this, like storing the last time the
player have seen its credits, computing the number of seconds since
then, and adding it just before printing again.

Don't forget to drop a line or two of doc to explain what you're
doing.
"""

class Shop():
    def __init__(self):
        """Initial stock, as an example about the class Shop managing its own rules
        """
        self.scavs = 100

    def player_enters(self, player):
        print("Welcome to the shop!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Here you can buy items which will produce caps, making your "
              "job easier!")
        time.sleep(1)
        shop_option = input("Would you like to (buy) or (exit)? \n")
        time.sleep(0.4)
        while shop_option == "buy":
            print("(S)cavenger (10 caps per second) : 500 caps")
            print("(C)ap magnet (20 caps per second) : 1000 caps")
            print("(F)actory cap press (100 caps per second) : 5000 caps")

            buy_option = input()

            if buy_option == "S":
                if self.scavs < 1:
                    print("Sorry, no moar scavs here")
                elif player.value < 500:
                    print("Sorry, you don't have enough caps. Get more!")
                elif player.value >= 500:
                    player.give(500)
                    player.scav += 1
                    print("Thank you for purchasing a Scavenger, "
                          "you now have ", player.scav, "Scavengers!")
                    shop_option = input("Please enter anything to exit "
                                        "the shop. \n")


class Player():
    """That's not completly necessary, but a good example, you can use a
    class to store information about something, and how to modify it.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 0
        self.scav = 0
        self.magnet = 0
        self.press = 0
        self.last_checked = datetime.now()

    def give(self, value):
        self._value -= value

    def receive(self, value):
        self._value += value

    @property
    def value(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        seconds = (now - self.last_checked).total_seconds()
        self.last_checked = now
        self._value += int((self.scav * 10 +
                            self.magnet * 20 +
                            self.press * 100) * seconds)
        return self._value

    def will_find_some_caps(self, rand_min, rand_max):
        """Here you should find a better name for this method. Naming is
        important (and complicated).
        """
        cap_chance = random.randint(rand_min, rand_max)
        print("You have found {} caps!".format(cap_chance))
        self._value += cap_chance
        print("\nYou now have {} caps!\n".format(self.value))

    def search(self):
        """Here, your succession of if/elsif is wrong, the first one is >= 50,
        which completly hide the second one, being >= 85.  I also
        doubt about using random to choose a range for random, you're
        not adding randomness to randomness, that's useless, what
        about a single, simple, self.will_find_some_caps(0, 250) ?
        """
        progress("Searching for caps.")
        search_chance = random.randint(0, 100)
        if search_chance >= 50:
            self.will_find_some_caps(10, 50)
        elif search_chance >= 85:
            self.will_find_some_caps(5, 10)
        elif search_chance >= 40:
            self.will_find_some_caps(25, 75)
        elif search_chance >= 25:
            self.will_find_some_caps(40, 120)
        elif search_chance <= 10:
            self.will_find_some_caps(60, 250)
        else:
            print("You haven't found any caps.")
            print("You now have {} caps!".format(self.value))

    def goto_shop(self, shop):
        shop.player_enters(self)

    def check(self):
        print("You have ", self.value, "caps!")
        print("You have ", self.scav, "Scavengers!")
        print("You have ", self.magnet, "Cap magnets!")
        print("You have ", self.press, "Factory cap presses!")


def progress(text):
    """Print text twice, with little sleeps in between
    """
    print(text + '.')
    time.sleep(.5)
    print(text + '..')
    time.sleep(.5)
    print(text + '...')
    time.sleep(1)


def cap_scavengerJob(player, shop):
    print("\nWelcome to Cap Scavenger!\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    progress("Searching for caps")

    start_chance = random.randint(65, 125)
    print("You have found ", start_chance, "caps!")
    player.receive(start_chance)
    print("Your goal is to find as many caps as you can!")
    while True:
        decision_search_1 = input(
            "Would you like to (search) for more caps, "
            "(check) how many caps you have or go to the (shop)? \n")
        if decision_search_1 == "search":
            player.search()
        elif decision_search_1 == "shop":
            player.goto_shop(shop)
        elif decision_search_1 == "check":
            player.check()
        elif decision_search_1 == "debug_mode":
            print("Debug Mode activated!")
            player.receive(10000)

player1 = Player()
main_shop = Shop()

while True:
    cap_scavengerJob(player1, main_shop)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't even know there was PEP8 rules xD. I'll try the program to see if works correctly, and give you some feedback, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, don't hesitate to speak and share with the Python community, you'll learn a lot, like on IRC on freenode, #python (or #python-fr if you're french, I am so I'm on the -fr one :p). Typically use http://irc.lc if you don't have an IRC client.